# Entity Framework: Erro ao criar o banco

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

estou utilizando o EF6 e estou com um problema ao utilizar o comando *Update-Database -Verbose -Force*. Da o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
PM> Update-Database -Verbose -Force
Using StartUp project 'PersonalTrainer.Presentation'.
Using NuGet project 'PersonalTrainer.Infra.Data'.
Specify the '-Verbose' flag to view the SQL statements being applied to the target database.
Target database is: 'TesteDb' (DataSource: PC-RAPHAEL\SQLEXPRESS, Provider: System.Data.SqlClient, Origin: Configuration).
No pending explicit migrations.
Applying automatic migration: 201607061619096_AutomaticMigration.
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Cliente_dbo.Endereco_EnderecoId]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cliente] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Cliente_dbo.Endereco_EnderecoId]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Endereco_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Endereco] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Endereco_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.ClienteAgenda_dbo.Cliente_ClienteId]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClienteAgenda] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ClienteAgenda_dbo.Cliente_ClienteId]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Treino_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Treino] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Treino_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.AnamneseAtividadeFisica_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnamneseAtividadeFisica] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AnamneseAtividadeFisica_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.AnamneseNutricional_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnamneseNutricional] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AnamneseNutricional_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.AnamneseGeral_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnamneseGeral] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AnamneseGeral_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.ComposicaoCorporal_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ComposicaoCorporal] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ComposicaoCorporal_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Financeiro_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Financeiro] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Financeiro_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Imc_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Imc] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Imc_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Parq_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Parq] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Parq_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Perimetria_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Perimetria] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Perimetria_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.RiscoCardiaco_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[RiscoCardiaco] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.RiscoCardiaco_dbo.Cliente_Cliente_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Endereco_dbo.Cidade_Cidade_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Endereco] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Endereco_dbo.Cidade_Cidade_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.Cidade_dbo.Estado_Estado_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Cidade] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Cidade_dbo.Estado_Estado_Id]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.ClienteAgenda_dbo.Agenda_AgendaId]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[ClienteAgenda] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.ClienteAgenda_dbo.Agenda_AgendaId]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.TreinoAgenda_dbo.Agenda_AgendaId]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreinoAgenda] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TreinoAgenda_dbo.Agenda_AgendaId]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.TreinoAgenda_dbo.Treino_ClienteId]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TreinoAgenda] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TreinoAgenda_dbo.Treino_ClienteId]
IF object_id(N'[dbo].[FK_dbo.AnamneseNutricional_dbo.Nutricionista_Nutricionista_Id]', N'F') IS NOT NULL
    ALTER TABLE [dbo].[AnamneseNutricional] DROP CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.AnamneseNutricional_dbo.Nutricionista_Nutricionista_Id]
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = N'IX_EnderecoId' AND object_id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Cliente]', N'U'))
    DROP INDEX [IX_EnderecoId] ON [dbo].[Cliente]
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.AnamneseAtividadeFisica.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
Caution: Changing any part of an object name could break scripts and stored procedures.
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.AnamneseNutricional.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.AnamneseGeral.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.ComposicaoCorporal.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Financeiro.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Imc.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Parq.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Perimetria.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.RiscoCardiaco.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Endereco.Cidade_Id', @newname = N'Cidade_CidadeId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Endereco.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.<NonQuery>b__0(DbCommand t, DbCommandInterceptionContext`1 c)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.NonQuery(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InterceptableDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.ExecuteSql(MigrationStatement migrationStatement, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction transaction, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsWithinNewTransaction(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection, DbInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatementsInternal(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbConnection connection)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClass30.<ExecuteStatements>b__2e()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.<>c__DisplayClass1.<Execute>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements, DbTransaction existingTransaction)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.ExecuteStatements(IEnumerable`1 migrationStatements)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.ExecuteOperations(String migrationId, VersionedModel targetModel, IEnumerable`1 operations, IEnumerable`1 systemOperations, Boolean downgrading, Boolean auto)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.AutoMigrate(String migrationId, VersionedModel sourceModel, VersionedModel targetModel, Boolean downgrading)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorLoggingDecorator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1 pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.<>c__DisplayClassc.<Update>b__b()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action mustSucceedToKeepDatabase)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update(String targetMigration)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.UpdateRunner.Run()
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner runner)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Update(String targetMigration, Boolean force)
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.UpdateDatabaseCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action command)
ClientConnectionId:d0dc8877-45a7-47c1-a868-1aca4f274208
Error Number:15248,State:1,Class:11
Either the parameter @objname is ambiguous or the claimed @objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.
PM>
```

Não sei qual objeto e nem qual coluna ele está se referindo.

Obrigado!

Comment: Pode por favor editar sua pergunta colocando o conteúdo da última Migration executada? Edite usando texto. Evite imagens.

Comment: Pronto, Cigano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está aqui:

```
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.RiscoCardiaco.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
...
EXECUTE sp_rename @objname = N'dbo.Endereco.Cliente_Id', @newname = N'Cliente_ClienteId', @objtype = N'COLUMN'
```

São dois objetos diferentes com o mesmo nome.

Você vai precisar ajustar manualmente sua *Migration* para que os `@newname` sejam diferentes entre eles.

Faça o ajuste e execute novamente. Ou ainda, derrubar o banco, apagar todas as *Migrations* e gerar uma nova *Migration* inicial pode ser uma opção.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Cigano! Estou aprendendo ainda EF. Aonde eu configuro isso? hehe
Na EntityTypeConfiguration?

Comment: Na própria Migration gerada. Se estiver usando Migrations automáticas, exclua o database.